# The child node "secret" at path "security.firewalls.main.remember_me" must be configured

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, remember-me

I have seen similar questions on SO, but could not find the answer to my issue. The Symfony2 [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html) explains how to implement the remember me feature.

Here is my `parameters.yml`:

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install parameters:
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: null
database_name: symfony
database_user: root
database_password: null
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null

# A secret key that's used to generate certain security-related tokens
secret: DSHJLREYQF98321BN23B1100F
```

and here is my `security.yml`:

```
security:

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user1:
                        password: user1
                        roles: 'ROLE_USER'
                    user2:
                        password: user2
                        roles: 'ROLE_USER'
                    admin:
                        password: admin
                        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'

    firewalls:
        default:
            remember_me:
                key:      "%secret%"
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path:     /

        # Need to create route in routing.yml, but no need in a controller
        secured_area:
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /

        # disables authentication for js,css, images, etc...
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        # fallback -> types of authentication
        main:
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: homepage
                check_path: login_check
                default_target_path: homepage
                failure_path: homepage
            remember_me:
                key:      "%secret%"
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path:     /

    encoders:
        # algorithm to encode passwords
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        # admin is user too
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER

    access_control:
        # require ROLE_ADMIN for admin page 
        - { path: ^/restricted/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # require ROLE_USER for user pages
        - { path: ^/restricted/user, roles: ROLE_USER }
        # The login form is embedded in the home page
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

But I get the following error message:

```
InvalidConfigurationException in ArrayNode.php line 237:
The child node "secret" at path "security.firewalls.main.remember_me" must be configured.
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I have changed `key: "%secret%"` to `secret: "%secret%"`. The error is gone, but a new one is thrown:

```
You must configure at least one remember-me aware listener
(such as form-login) for each firewall that has remember-me enabled.
```

I solved it by moving the `remember_me:` configuration under the `main` firewall.

```
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: homepage
            check_path: login_check
            default_target_path: homepage
            failure_path: homepage
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
        remember_me:
            secret:      "%secret%"
            lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
            path:     /
```

Comment: Maybe a `clear:cache` ?

Comment: What version of Symfony are you using ? I read that `key` got undocumentedly renamed to `secret` somewhere along the 2.8 version ...

Comment: Yep, the docs are out of date https://github.com/symfony/security-bundle/commits/04f370c3b4fe146798808f2bdd7198dc946b72ff/Tests/DependencyInjection/Fixtures/yml/remember_me_options.yml

Comment: I am on Symfony 2.8.0

Comment: I have opened a doc issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/5765

Comment: @tchap If you create the answer, I'll approve it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `key` parameter got undocumentedly renamed to `secret` somewhere along the 2.8 version ... so you should do :

```
    remember_me:
        secret:      "%secret%"
        lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
        path:     /
```

See https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/5761